# Slide div from right to left

Tags: jquery, html, css

I the below example, when I click on link `message-window` the div slides from left to right, but when I change its property `left:-100px` to `right:-100px` the slide works but a horizontal scroll appears. How can we prevent the horizontal scroll appearing?

HTML:

```
<div class="message-window">Here I am !</div>
<div class="red-box">Fixed div</div>

<a href="#" class="photo-details-messages" style="position:absolute; top:400px">Show/hide Slide Panel</a>
```

CSS:

```
.red-box, .message-window {
    height:350px;
}

.red-box {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}

.message-window {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100%;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.photo-details-messages').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.message-window');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"-100%"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0px"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alpeshlahad/0h5rhsrk/)

Comment: I want ".message-window" slide from right to left without horizontal scroll.

Comment: you can try this tutorial for better result

http://www.themeswild.com/read/slide-navigation-left-to-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper div with height and width, set the overflow property to hidden in order to get rid of the horizontal scroll issue.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="message-window">Here I am !</div>
    <div class="red-box">Fixed div</div>
</div>


<a href="#" class="photo-details-messages" style="position:absolute; top:400px">Show/hide Slide Panel</a>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
  width:100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.red-box, .message-window {
    height:350px;
}

.red-box {
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}

.message-window {
    width:100%;
    z-index:2;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    background:#f90;
    color:#000;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.photo-details-messages').click(function(){
    var hidden = $('.message-window');
    if (hidden.hasClass('visible')){
        hidden.animate({"left":"100%"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
    } else {
        hidden.animate({"left":"0"}, "slow").addClass('visible');
    }
    });
});
```

[check this](https://jsfiddle.net/sesubash/0h5rhsrk/2/)

Comment: Perfect solution. Bravo!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 2 small changes

```
<div class="rel">
    <div class="message-window">Here I am !</div>
    <div class="red-box">Fixed div</div>
</div>
```

and in CSS

```
.rel{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position:relative;
  height:350px;
  width:100%;
}
```