# Two buttons for sliding the same div but in different ways (right to left and left to right)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just need to slide div from right to left and back using two buttons.

I provided a piece of code, but div slide normally only for the click on   buttonStart, on buttonClose it is not sliding.

```js
//custom code start
$(function() {
  $('.showButton').click(function() {
    $('.hidden').show();
    $('.show').hide();
  });
  $('.hideButton').click(function() {
    $('.hidden').hide();
    $('.show').show();
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  //localStorage.removeItem('show'); //to unset an item
  var show = sessionStorage.getItem('show');
  if (show === 'true') {
    $('#content101').show();
  }

  $("#buttonStart").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#content101').show();
    sessionStorage.setItem('show', 'true');
  });
  if (document.querySelector("#content101").style.display == "block") {
    $("#buttonStart").hide();
    $("#buttonClose").show();
  } else {
    $("#buttonStart").show();
    $("#buttonClose").hide();
  }
});

$("#buttonStart").click(function() {
  {
    $("#content101").toggle("slide");
  }
});
$("#buttonClose").click(function() {
  {
    $("#content101").toggle("slide");
  }
});
//custom code end
```

```css
#content101 {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 60px;
  width: 740px;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<button id="buttonStart" class="showButton show">Show div</button>
<button id="buttonClose" class="hideButton hidden">Hide div</button>
<div id="content101" class="hidden">Content</div>
```

I want, that after clicking on buttonClose it slides back.

Comment: Check out the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36305854/slide-div-from-right-to-left

Comment: please add your html

Comment: @RachelGallen added

Comment: @ArtyProf edited answer left/right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be over-complicating the jquery. You could definitely simplify it to a single simple function. Hide one button in the css (depending on whether you want it to be hidden or visible at the start)

See sample snippet :

```js
$("#buttonStart").click(function() {
  {
    $("#content101").toggle("slide");
    $('#buttonStart').hide();
    $('#buttonClose').show();
  }
});
$("#buttonClose").click(function() {
  {
    $("#content101").toggle("slide");
    $('#buttonStart').show();
    $('#buttonClose').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
#content101 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #f0e68c;
  width: 100%;
}

button {
  margin-top: 110px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

#buttonStart {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content101">
  <p>
    I want this to slide open and close
  </p>
</div>
<br>
<button id="buttonStart">
Show
</button>

<button id="buttonClose">
Hide
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle a single button and content with a single chained function.

```
$('.btn').on('click', function() {...
```

Any tag with class `.btn` is clicked...

```
$(this).toggleClass('hide show')...
```

Toggle its class `.hide/.show` to change its text (see CSS)

```
.next('.hidden').animate({width:'toggle'}, 750);
```

Get the next tag with the class `.hidden` and toggle it left/right

Also use class avoid #id. In the demo class is used which allows us to control duplicate tags with just one function.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('show hide').next('.hidden').animate({
    width: 'toggle'
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
  height: 30x;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
}

.hide:before {
  content: 'Hide ';
}

.show:before {
  content: 'Show ';
}
```

```html
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<button class="btn show">Content</button>
<div class="hidden">Content</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example with toggle and css transition.

HTML

```
<button id="button">Toggle div</button>
<div id="slide" class="transition"></div>
```

JS

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#slide').toggleClass('open');
})
```

CSS

```
#slide {
    background: black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    left: -110%;
}

.open {
    left: 0px !important;
}

.transition {
  -webkit-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: left 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

https://jsfiddle.net/o2xa0wjr/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple example.

There is two example, Jq and UI choose one that suit you more

```js
var box = $(".box");
// this is Jq example
$("input").first().click(function() {
    if (box.is(":hidden")) // then show it
        box.show("slow");
    else 
        box.hide("slow");
});

// Jq UI Example using animate
$("input").last().click(function() {
    if (box.is(":hidden")) // then show it
        box.show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
    else 
        box.hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 500);
});
```

```css
.box {
    width:90%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="button" value="Jquery only" />

<input type="button" value="Jquery UI" />

<div class="box"></div>
```